# How to format resuts of Google analytics date. ga:date

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

Currently I am using :

```
service.data().ga().get(
            ids='ga:' + profile_id,
            start_date='2018-07-21',
            end_date='2018-07-26',
            metrics='ga:users',
            dimensions='ga:date'
            ).execute()
```

And I get this result:

```
[['20180721', '440'], ['20180722', '476'], ['20180723', '40'], ['20180724', '775'], ['20180725', '491'], ['20180726', '228']]
```

I want the date '20180721', etc as "2018-07-21" format.
Does google analytics ([Getting started with python API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)) in python provide anything to get formatted date output.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, for `ga:date` dimension, the date of the session is formatted as `YYYYMMDD`. However, if you're comfortable with reformatting the date yourself, you can try doing something like this (Note: I'm using the response directly):

```
a = [['20180721', '440'], ['20180722', '476'], ['20180723', '40'], ['20180724', '775'], ['20180725', '491'], ['20180726', '228']]
a = [[x[0][:4] + '-' + x[0][4:6] + '-' + x[0][6:], x[1]] for x in a]
```

Also, parsing it using the `datetime` module and getting the formatted date string is supposed to be a cleaner approach, but this method is more concise and does exactly what's required (and is faster too) since we know the exact format of the date string

Answer (score 0):

If using pandas you could use the pandas to_datetime() method:

```
import pandas as pd

result = [['20180721', '440'], ['20180724', '775'], ['20180725', '491'], ['20180726', '228']]

formatted_dates = [pd.to_datetime(d[0], format="mixed") for d in result]
```